How to architecturally effectively spawn Perl processes that have a resource intensive init process?
Stack:

Nginx
FCGI
CGI::Fast
HTML::Template::Compiled
Redis
CentOS Linux 7.9
spawn-fcgi


I have a Perl application that runs on the above stack.
On process init it does a lot of loading of big hashes and other data into global variables that are mostly preloaded and cached in a distributed Redis install.
To start the application spawn-fcgi creates 6-8 processes on a port nginx then connects to trhough their fcgi module.
The challenge:
The init process is computing and time consuming; and doing that concurrently six times peaks CPU and overall leads to a ~20-25 second delay before the next web request can be served. And the initial request to each of the six processes has that delay.
I tried loading the content in question directly from Redis on demand but the performance keeping it in memory is naturally much better (minus the initial delay).
is there an architectural pattern that I am not considering here? I am thinking of things as eg. only spinning up one process, having it initialize and then clone(?) it a few times for serving more requests.
I could also think of a way where only 1 process is spawned at a time and once it completes initiation the next one starts; would need to verify that spawn-fcgi can support this.
So my question to this community is if I am missing an obvious better solution than what is in place right now / what I am considering.
Cross posted at:
https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/1dbgu9i/is_there_a_better_way_to_initialize_my_concurrent/

Re "and doing that concurrently six times", Do o it pre-fork instead of post-fork to reduce it to once!

@ikegami everything that can be done pre-fork is already done pre-fork; aka everything is loaded into redis. the load up time is filling global process variables  from redis into the workers taking the web requests

What are you talking about? You're doing all this work for each child created by the FCGI server instead of in the FCGI server before it forks them. Do it in the FCGI server.

@ikegami likely have a knowledge gap here; what constitutes the FCGI server in this context; nginx? and how would the spawned child processes "access" the global variables from "the server:? right now spawn-fcgi is started and monitored by a separate script starting the porcesses at port XXXX and all nginx has is the  fastcgi_pass command to that port with some extra header and cache configuration. per the thread, am I indeed missing something obvious? Thanks in advance.

Re "likely have a knowledge gap here; what constitutes the FCGI server in this context; nginx?", No, nginx talks to your FCGI server. The program that handles that FCGI requests. /// Re "how would the spawned child processes "access" the global variables from "the server:?", Forking a process creates an identical copy of it

thank you @ikegami; what you describe seems to be a bit of a different pattern/tools/libraries then at play here? in our case the forking happens on command line through spawn-fcgi which gets handed a perl script that gets initiated X number of times at port XXXX; that perl script receives request in loop a la
#!perl
use CGI::Fast;
do_some_initialization();
while ($q = CGI::Fast->new) {
process_request($q);
}
it seems what you describe would be a single instance startup, that does initialization and then clone itself? are there different tools/libraries at play in your approach?

@ikegami maybe you are suggesting that instead of spawn-fcgi forking our processes we have our request dispatcher do so programmatically in the lines of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592157/whats-the-proper-way-to-fork-in-fastcgi ?

@tomypro I agree with ikegami, what you describe doesn't make sense. Could be a misunderstanding of how FastCGI works. We need something concrete. Can you make a simplified version of your application and show us the code and configuration files? It doesn't have to actually do anything, just to illustrate how you're receiving requests and spawning processes.

@schwern @ikegami happy to; though the above is 90% of it.
a dispatcher.pl process is spawned 8 times by https://linux.die.net/man/1/spawn-fcgi /usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -u nginx -p 9001 -F 8 -P ./logs/fcgi.pid -- ./dispatcher.pl with the dispatcher.pl holding this pseudo #!perl use CGI::Fast; do_some_initialization() #load global variables stored in redis; while ($q = CGI::Fast->new) { process_request($q); } in nginx the fcgi intergation is also cookie cutter from nginx configuration fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001; with some more settings for header and caching commands

so I will say what we do here is pretty much straight forward from the docs on how to operate fast cgi with Fast::CGI and nginx. Yet I wholeheartedly agree that its not efficient or intelligent hence this post in the first place. There seems to be a missing piece here of a FastCGI server from which we would fork/clone processes with the data initiatiliation being done once on startup. my assumption at this point is though that it would require a different set of tools/libraries

Sounds like your server is split across two programs (spawn-fcgi and dispatcher.pl), and that you end up doing fork -> exec -> init data instead of init data -> fork because of this poor division. I previously used this modified version of FCGI::Daemon 0.20111121. This patch was applied to FCGI::ProcManager.

That is exactly what it is @ikegami — thank your for your patience. I will look into these libraries; its exactly what I expected would be needed to support an architecture like you described. May come back with questions but many thanks so far.

@ikegami going through the implementation cycles of this and some questions popped up in case you are still paying attention:
FCGI::Daemon and FCGI::ProManager are two different options for FCGI servers correct? I would not use them in combination?
If I use FCGI::ProcManager I would call it from the CLI and have it listed to a certain port?
Most importantly, when using either, would I still use Nginx FCI module to proxy the requests to the port / socket in question?

FCGI::Daemon uses FCGI::ProcManager

I see; any thoughts on the NGINX question? does NGINX in this setup just become a dump proxy?
